# Laravel Auth return to index

Tags: php, laravel

Can I redirect to the previous page someone if not logged in? Also, is it possible to create a hierarchy system for users?

I tried this:

```
if(!(Auth::check())) { 
            header("Location: {{ route('cooperado.index') }});
}
```

But i not even got an error message, just doesn't work. I'm starting at laravel so it's kind of hard to fully understand how it works.

Comment: are you use laravel default auth package?

Comment: You should use `return redirect()->route('cooperado.index');`

Comment: yes im using default auth package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using Constructor in controller

You also can use middleware in order to redirect unauthenticated user back or somewhere else.

```
public method __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Add this code in your controller so all methods within particular controller

-direct from route defination

```
Route::get('/path/',controller@method)->name('cooperado.index')->middleware('auth');
```

- Redirection

using this method unauthenticated user will redirect to login page.
in order to edit redirection page you can change '@redirectTo' method 
in

> app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

file.

Comment: can i use the same logic for a hierarchy system for users? like an admin user i mean

Comment: for admin user you can create 'admin' guard.. here a link for multiauth in laravel. This tutorial is amazing.. if you are beginner than you should check this out..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M

Comment: If you want to learn more in laravel than check out https://laracasts.com/ - jefferey has amazing teaching methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(Auth::check())) { 
           return redirect()->route('cooperado.index');
}
```

You mention in your question also wants to return previous page then use following but **i'm not recommended this** because if your first login effort fails then login failed' page becomes your previous page and second login effort succeeds then you are redirected to login page again because it's your previous page.

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Is the easiest way to do this. 
And you can also pass message, will displayed on when user redirect back from main page.

```
if(!Auth::check) {
      return Redirect::back()->with('error','Please Login');
}
```